# updating yarn.scheduler memory

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

Total Noob here, I installed Cloudera Manager on single node on aws ec2. I followed the install wizard but when I try running

spark-shell or pyspark I get the following error message:

```
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (1024+384     
MB) is above the max threshold (1024 MB) of this cluster! Please check 
the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 
'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.
```

Can somebody explain to me what is going on or where to begin reading? Total noob, here so any help or direction is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The required executor memory is above the maximum threshold. You need to increase the YARN memory.

The values of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` both live in the config file `yarn-site.xml` which is managed by Cloudera Manager in your case.

`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` is the amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.

`yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` is the maximum memory in mb that cab be allocated per yarn container. The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in MBs. Memory requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.

You can read more on the definitions and default values here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

1. In the Cloudera Manager user interface, go to Yarn service > Configurations > Search and increase the values of them.
2. Restart YARN for the changes to take effect.

Comment: How do you restart Yarn?

Comment: @Anna Home -> Status tab, click to the right of the service name and select Restart.

Comment: If you're using Cloudera manager or something else to manage a cluster then I wouldn't recommend doing it on the command line per node. Cloudera manager will propagate over your cluster for you and report back the status safely. If you wanted to just restart it on single node then you can do so through Cloudera Manager UI

Comment: I don't use Cloudera, just cannot figure out how to restart Yarn on Centos.

Comment: You could try running `sudo stop hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager` followed by `sudo start hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager`.